# Why is this hashmap not returning the expected value

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm try to sort a hashmap based on its value. For this I'm using a List. Here is my code :

```
//The original hashmap that needs to be sorted
Map<Subject,Integer> originalMap = new HashMap<>();
originalMap.put(new Subject("English"),1);
originalMap.put(new Subject("French"),5);
originalMap.put(new Subject("Tamil"),6);
originalMap.put(new Subject("Chinese"),3);

//storing the hashmap in a list so that it can be sorted 
List<Map.Entry<Subject,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(originalMap.entrySet());
list.sort((i,j)->Integer.compare(i.getValue(),j.getValue()));

Map<Subject,Integer> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<Subject,Integer> item:list){
           finalMap.put(item.getKey(),item.getValue());
}

finalMap.forEach((i,j)-> System.out.print(j+" "));
```

I expect the code to print

```
1 3 5 6
```

but the output is

```
6 3 5 1
```

Also, does the sorting on hashmap makes sense as hashmap do not guarantee the order of elements.

Comment: Please don't call something `xxxList` if it's not some kind of `List`.  That kind of thing makes your code WAY harder to understand.  Particularly when you've got a real `List` in the mix as well.  It would be much better to call your `Map` objects `originalMap` and `finalMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have now made corrections in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not sort a HashMap. This is, because HashMap objects are storing the values unsorted in the memory.

You can test this:
Run the code multiple times and I would bet, that you will become different results (not sure).

**Edit:**

You can try LinkedHashMap for this.
Objects of this class have a pointer to their next and to their previous object, and because of that, they can be sorted.

Comment: *Run the code multiple times and I would bet, that you will become different results.* Not likely. The order is not random, just undefined.

Comment: Then I would have lost the bet; I will test this! Thanks for this comment! But the LinkedHashSet will do the trick because it has "pointers" to the previous and next element.

Comment: Or more accurately, it's defined by the implementation, not by the specification.  But certainly, like shmosel, I'd expect to see the same order every time the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your finalList is a HashMap, order is not guaranteed, use LinkedHashMap in place